# Is it possible to login nextcloud with rocket chat oauth?

Tags: nextcloud, rocket.chat

here Iam trying to integrate my rocket chat with nextcloud for storage.
is It possible for make oauth rocket chat as server and nextcloud as client ?
all i can see is how to login rocket-chat using other vendor, like google, facebook,nextcloud I want the other way around, let me know if it is possible and what tool i should use to make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.

yes, they have this feature for integration rocketchat with nextcloud.

you can find in the `Oauth apps` in `rocket chat` and `sociallogin` in `nextclound`

and dont forget to add `id` to response oauth server from rocket chat